# Install a Git Client with GUI

Tags: gui, git

I known using git on the command line is the prefered method by a lot of Linux users.

But has somebody have successfully installed and used a Git Client with GUI on a RPI2 / 3 with raspbian ?

I am aksing that question, becasue i didn't find on the web any answer, and a GUI is a most 'convenient' way to manage conflict for example.
Best regards.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux Welcome -- but purely linux oriented questions belong on our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), although generally I recommend you *first try a search engine* instead of asking other people to do it for you.